# Is PHP dynamic enough?

Tags: php, programming-languages, dynamic

As far as I know, PHP is a dynamic type language. We don't need to declare variable and don't need to define data type of variables and function return.

I found [an article on sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2006/01/16/design-patterns-in-dynamic-programming/) and one commenter said PHP is not dynamic enough because...

> PHP does to many things at
>   compile-time (like the whole “static”
>   “self::” stuff) instead run-time.

I'm curious with it. Can someone define what is dynamic type language in simplest form? Is PHP dynamic enough?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the article is talking about dynamic typing at all, but rather the lack of things like reflection and other "dynamic" run-time features, such as the ability to extend a class that has already been defined (like you can in Ruby or JavaScript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is PHP dynamic enough?

This is purely subjective, but I'd say "yes" : as long as it allows you/me do do what is needed from it, it is *good/dynamic/fast/whatever* enough ;-)

About the static/self stuff : there have been some great improvements in PHP 5.3 *(released at the end of June this year)* : there is now [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/lsb), which has been implemented precisely to answer that concern :

> This feature was named "late static
>   bindings" with an internal perspective
>   in mind. "Late binding" comes from the
>   fact that `static::`  will no longer be
>   resolved using the class where the
>   method is defined but it will rather
>   be computed using runtime information.
>   It was also called a "static binding"
>   as it can be used for (but is not
>   limited to) static method calls.

Of course, PHP 5.3 is not yet widely available... But that'll come, one day or another ^^